# Allow EventListener to get pageX and PageY without keeping it on top the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I have a basic slider on `mousedown` it adds another event to check the movement `mousemove`

It's all working as expected, but I want to make the slider element keeps changing it's `x` value even if the mouse isn't on top of the element

for example:
On YouTube, go to any video and hold down the timeline progress bar and move your mouse on the y-axis's and then move on x-axis's, you might notice that you don't have be on top of the timeline element to keep moving it.

I'm trying to get a similar effect
here.

I'm asking this question because I don't know what to search for, or how can I solve it

code:

```js
const sliderElement = document.getElementById("slider");
const conH = document.getElementsByClassName("con-h")[0]
conH.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
conH.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
let x = event.clientX;
sliderElement.style.width = x + "px"
})
});
```

```css
.con-h{
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
}
#slider{
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="con-h">
<div id="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the problem with listening for the `mousemove` on the document or window instead of the  `conH` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div in the background and just get the mouse's X position from the background div. Uncomment the `background-color: green;` to see the full size.

```js
const sliderElement = document.getElementById("slider");
const conH = document.getElementsByClassName("con-h")[0]
const bg = document.getElementsByClassName("bg")[0];

conH.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  bg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    let x = event.clientX;
    if (x < 101) {
      sliderElement.style.width = `${x}px`
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.con-h {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}

#slider {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.bg {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  # This is just to show how big the BG Element is,
  # in normal use it would have no bg-color
  #background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="con-h">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like t.niese said, you could listen to the mousemove event of the body.

Additionnally, you have to calculate the slider's position in the page.

And an advise: Do not register event handlers inside another one. It always leads to weird issues.

```js
const sliderElement = document.getElementById("slider");
const conH = document.getElementsByClassName("con-h")[0]

// Use a flag to know if the slider is active
let sliderActive = false

// Slider's handler
conH.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  sliderActive = !sliderActive
});

// Body handler to deactivate slider
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  if(sliderActive && event.target !== conH && event.target !== sliderElement){
    sliderActive = false
  }
})

// Body handler to set slider value
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  let x = event.clientX;
  const conHLeft = Math.round(conH.getBoundingClientRect().left)

  if (sliderActive) {
    sliderElement.style.width = (x - conHLeft) + "px"
  }
})
```

```css
.con-h {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;  /* To avoid the slider grow bigger than its container */
}

#slider {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="con-h">
  <div id="slider">
  </div>
</div>
```